# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998 throw err; ^ Cannot find solution to this error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ajax, express, nodemon

Just opened my IDE for my project on react and this weird stubborn error popped up on my nodemon server.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Hammad\ngo_project\index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.12.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I tried deleting and reinstalling node_modules folder and even package_lock but still the same error is popping.

Comment: Please share the file structure or package.json

Comment: Which way you are using for file imports `require` or `import`? And if you are using `import` syntax do you have `"type": "module"` (ES 6 modules) enabled in your package.json?

Answer (score 1):

You will execute the `node index.js` command
Want to launch a file with the name `index.js`
You are in the folder of your project, you have this path: `C:\Users\Hammad\ngo_project`
Your file is not in this folder, maybe you have a folder called "js" or some other name that contains your `index.js` file.
When you launch the `node index.js` command.
Node Js is looking for your file in the project `C:\Users\Hammad\ngo_project` Node Js does not go to other subcathologists, therefore it does not find your `index.js` file.
You need to move the `index.js` file to your `ngo_project` folder.
After that, repeat the launch of the `node index.js` command.

**Also important!**
If you have `"type": "module"` in `package.json`
You need to use in your `index.js` connection like this: example `import fetch from 'node-fetch';`
If `"type": "CommonJS"` is specified in the `package.json` file or not specified at all.
You need to use in your `index.js` connection like this: example `const fetch = require('node-fetch');`
*Good luck!*

Answer (score -2):

Try use Yarn, not npm. I use Yarn and it help me.

Delete node_modules and package-lock.json, after that in terminal write yarn install